# I'm having trouble updating two excel files side by side

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

By clicking on the "Synchronize" button we will collect the stock numbers of the 2 tables and print them on the stock number of the 1st table.

I have two excel files side by side and I'm having trouble updating them
(addition + transfer).

Synchronize

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataSet ds;
        DataSet ds2;
        OpenFileDialog of;
        OpenFileDialog ofl;
        FileStream fs;
        FileStream fst;
        IExcelDataReader okuyucu;
        IExcelDataReader okuyucu1;
        DataTable dt;
        DataTable dts;
        DataRow new_data_row;
        int adet;
        int adet2;
        int StokNo1;
        int StokNo2;


        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Synchronize Button
        {
            int Adet = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index.ToString());
            int Adet2 = Int32.Parse(dataGridView2.Columns[2].Index.ToString());
            int StokNo1 = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Columns[0].Index.ToString());
            int StokNo2 = Int32.Parse(dataGridView2.Columns[0].Index.ToString());


            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                {
                    StokNo1 = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Columns[0].Index.ToString());//The StokNo belonging to DataGridWiew1.
                    Adet = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index.ToString());//The number belonging to DataGridWiew1.

                }
            }


            foreach (DataTable dt2 in ds2.Tables)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ds2.Tables.Count; j++)
                {
                    StokNo2 = Int32.Parse(dataGridView2.Columns[0].Index.ToString());//The StokNo belonging to DataGridWiew2.
                    Adet2 = Int32.Parse(dataGridView2.Columns[2].Index.ToString());//The number belonging to DataGridWiew2.
                }
            }

            if ((StokNo1 == StokNo2))//StokNo is Equal
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    int toplam = adet + adet2;
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(toplam);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add();//If stokno is not equal add to the last listed
            }

        }




        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            save.Filter = "Excel|*.xls";
            save.OverwritePrompt = true;
            save.CreatePrompt = true;

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter kayıt = new StreamWriter(save.FileName);
                kayıt.WriteLine(dataGridView1.ToString());
                kayıt.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if the stock number is equal to add to list , I want to update the number according to the stock code I want to add it at the end if the stock code is different

Comment: (This particular) Stack Overflow is an English only site. Please translate your question title.

Comment: I corrected the translation. sorry @JeroenMostert

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it fits a [mcve]. There is too much code here and we don't know which of the handlers is for the "synchronize" button